# How to decrease motion times in vim, specifically decreasing key depress reaction time?

Tags: performance, vim

I'm wondering how to navigate vim more quickly within paragraphs. It seems ( ) are not as efficient as just holding down E/W/B if it is a very small paragraph because of the tendency to overshoot your intended location, which I still do, thus I end up doing something like EEEEEEE/BBBB/EE/B to get to the intended spot. On a related note, how can you make it so that when you hold down a motion key in vim, the motion will begin being implemented faster?

Comment: That's not a vim setting, that's an OS setting.

Comment: `)))))` is still just as bad as `eeeee`. Use semantic movement more. What is it in the paragraph that you want to get to?

Comment: I'm just constantly trying to move through vim but since I'm new I'm only using it for small programs and thus I am wondering what the best movement  method is for jumping around on the page.

Comment: just revisiting this... what is a semantic movement?

Answer (score 0):

Vim offers a lot of ways to make your cursor movement more efficient. A few of them include:

- `f<character>`   ﻿﻿          Jump to the next occurrence of "`<character>`"
- `gj` or `gk`                 Treat a wrapped line as multiple lines
- `<number>b` or `<number>w`   Move `<number>` words
- `0`                          Jump to column 0